# How do I install pygame? 'pip' isn't working

Tags: pygame

I'm trying to learn pygame but I'm having trouble installing it because when I go to terminal and type "pip install pygame" but an error pops up and I'm not too sure how to fix it.

This is what happens:

```
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip install pygame
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [],
    CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7a1D.png)

If anyone can help me fix this I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: Do you have Python installed?  If so, try `python -m ensurepip` to install pip.

Answer (score -1):

does `pip --version` return anything?

I think you just need to add pip to PATH.

In Windows, open cmd.exe and find the location of PYTHON_HOME using `where python`. Now add this location to your environment variable PATH using:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;<PYTHON_HOME>\Scripts
```

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jw_MuM2BOuI) tutorial to help.

Comment: Just tried that and it output:
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip --version
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Does this mean i dont have it installed? How would I install it? :)

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 11

Comment: Follow @mkimball's advice.  You probably do not have `pip` yet.  That is assuming you have already installed python itself.